# Type 'MainVC' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate'

Tags: swift, peek

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but my class MainVC can't conform to the protocol UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate. I've searched all over the internet but couldn't find a single person who had the same issue.

This is my class:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {}
```

Is it because of another protocol?

I'm trying to peek from a cell in a tableView.
The view is build in Storyboard.

I'm using Xcode 7.2.1 and Swift 2.2.

Comment: Where does the compiler complain? Have you implemented the two required protocol methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Class conforms to protocol" means "class implements methods declared in this protocol". As we can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate_Protocol/), your protocol has 2 required methods. If you implement them (or at least create stubs, i.e. empty methods), compiler will not complain no more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just implemented the pop method and now it works. But why do i have to implement both of them?

Comment: Because they are both required.